# How can I find the local static pressure right in the front of a moving speaker cone?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, acoustics

To simplify things: Imagine a speaker with a perfectly rigid cone in a sealed enclosure (so we only have to care about the waves produced in the outer side).

I can have the information of position, velocity and acceleration of the cone at any given moment.

From that I want to find the sound pressure (the static pressure of the air) right in front of the cone, or at least to what it is proportional to.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a standard problem in acoustics. Google for "piston in a plane baffle". Only special cases (e.g. a circular piston in an infinite sized baffle) have closed-form solutions.

Comment: @alephzero, but that solution gives the pressure for points in space around the piston, right at the surface of the piston it seems to give no results